# Pandas python: Create function to merge two dataframes based on defined list of columns

Tags: python, pandas

In the script that I am writing, I want to frequently repeat the same piece of code, where I create a "numerator" dataframe with one group by, and then a "denominator" dataframe with a different group by. I then merge the two together so that I have the numerator and denominator in one place. I am trying to create a function where all I have to pass to it is the list of fields I want included in the numerator and denominator.

Here is the function:

```
  def calcfractions(self, df, numlist, denomlist):
    print("test 1")
    numlist.append(denomlist)
    selectlist = numlist
    selectlist.append("TeamID")
    selectlist.append("PlayerID")

    print("test 2")
    numdf = df[selectlist].groupby(numlist).agg({"PlayerID": "count"})
    denomdf = df[selectlist].groupby(denomlist).agg({"PlayerID": "count"})

    print("test 3")
    mergeddf = pd.merge(numdf, denomdf, on=denomlist)

    print("test 4")
    return mergeddf
```

Here is the script I'm trying to use it in:

```
 def team_pr(self, df1):
    numlist = ['PlayerLevel']
    denomlist = ['TeamName', 'Year']

    mergeddf = self.calcfractions(df1, numlist, denomlist)
    print(mergeddf.head(2))
```

However, when I run this, I only get to printing "test 2" in def calcfractions, something fails after that point. I think it might have to do with trying to append denomlist to numlist. Any thoughts?

EDIT: The script doesn't "fail", there is no error. It just ends.

Comment: Why are you using `self` outside of a class?

Comment: @cohdez it is within a class, sorry i just didn't include the entire code

Comment: *something fails after that point*...so you receive no error? Please post traceback or exception message.

Comment: @parfait no error message, it prints hello 1, hello 2, says "setting an array element with a sequence" and then the script ends

Comment: Well, there is a missing right parenthesis in the line `print('test 2' <------ missing ")"`. Unclear whether this exists in your source as well.

Comment: @StarFox that was just a copying mistake, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after concocting my own dataframe with bogus values and trying to work through this, I have found that I run into a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`. This is due to the fact that you are appending a list to a list and trying to use that as a column index in your df:

```
numlist = ['PlayerLevel']
denomList = ['TeamName', 'Year']
numlist.append(denomlist) # as you suspected this is problematic:

print(numlist)
['PlayerLevel', ['TeamName', 'Year']]
```

Try this instead:

```
numlist += denomlist
```

Is this entire provided snippet wrapped up in some `try: except:` clause somewhere? In any case, if this doesn't solve your problem, please provide us with a small version of your dataframe.

---

**Edit:** From the [docs on exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions): "The last except clause may omit the exception name(s), to serve as a wildcard. Use this with extreme caution, since it is easy to mask a real programming error in this way!"

Definitely look through the linked docs, but here is the gist of the immediate problem. It's considered poor practice to write try/except clauses like this:

```
try:
    # do stuff
except:
    # do different/more stuff if original stuff fails
```

because the `except:` excepts `Exceptions` of *all* types. To parrot the quoted docs, **this makes it seem like there is no error.** Furthermore, as this entire question exemplifies, **this makes it impossible to know what is exactly causing an error** (if you even manage to detect one). In nearly all cases, you should have an expectation of what kind of error your code can throw, so your try/except's should look like:

```
try:
    # do stuff here
except ValueError: # or whatever type of child of Exception()
    # do different/more stuff if original stuff fails
```

If you **have** to do a wildcard `except:` for some crazy reason, ideally refactor, so that such a thing isn't necessary, but at the very least, `print()` *some* kind of message indicating that the `try:` failed.

Generally, to avoid this problem (as it relates to wildcard or even specific exceptions), **do your best to ensure that the try/except clause wraps as little code as is necessary to accomplish your goals.**

Comment: yes thank you! That was the problem, I'm now encountering other problems, but that fixed that one. And yes it is wrapped in a try: except: . Is that why I'm not getting an error thrown?

Answer (score 0):

You are not capturing the return value from `calcfractions`. in `team_pr`, change to `merged_df = self.calcfractions(df1, numlist, denomlist)` then `print(merged_df.head(2))` to see what you get.

This is assuming these are methods of a class. If they are just functions, just do away with the whole `self` bit, it's syntax used for classes only, to pass in the instance as the first argument.

Comment: it is within a class. I changed it to this:     `mergeddf = self.calcfractions(df1, numlist, denomlist)
    print(mergeddf.head(2))` but still nothing happened (no error though)

Comment: @AVD that's cool, first section should hopefully solve your problem then.

Comment: there's still nothing happening, it's not printing anything

Comment: neither, it just runs, but doesn't produce anything

Comment: not sure if it matters, this is how team_pr gets called: `self.team_pr(df1.copy())`

Comment: @AVD so are you sure the line `print(mergeddf.head(2))` is executed? how about doing a `print('about to print dataframe')` just before that?

Comment: it appears you're right, not as much of the code is executing as I thought, I've updated the problem above